# Check cell for multiple strings and return specific values

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to create a Google Sheet formula that searches for a word in a longer string and returns a specific value based on the string being searched.

I can achieve this in Excel but I need this to work in Google Sheets.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The "**Sort**" column is retrieving the value based on checking if the word in column "**C**" exists in column "**A**".

I've tried using wildcard search but this isn't working for me in Google Sheets, and other examples I've seen online don't seem to allow me to return multiple values.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula may fit you:

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,JOIN("|",FILTER(C:C,C:C<>""))),"none")
```

[image]

Here're some useful links:

[REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)

[JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en)

[FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)

Comment: Brilliant - I have no idea what the formula consists of so will have to research so I understand it, thanks for your help